# RHEL 7.9 and OS compatibility with DELL server GEN 15 PowerEdge

Tags: redhat, dell, kernel

we want to purchase the `dell servers Gen 15` machines ,

total machines should be around 85 servers

these servers should used for Hadoop cluster as data-node machines

and the OS should be RHEL 7.9 version

so before we continue to purchase the `dell servers Gen 15` machines

we want to know if there are some limitation or exceptions when installing RHEL 7.9 on DELL HW Gen15 ,

or maybe what we need to be aware when installing RHEL7.9 on that servers?

Comment: You need to confirm it by model. The RHEL operating system support matrix is here: https://catalog.redhat.com/hardware/search?p=1&c_catalog_channel=Server&c_catalog_vendor=Dell%20EMC|Dell&c_version=Red%20Hat%20Enterprise%20Linux%207

Comment: I see many servers but how to know if they are GEN15?

Comment: Do you have Maintenance Support 2 or ELS contract with RedHat. Because RHEL 7 is out of Maintenance year 2020?

Comment: I think we have for RHEL 7.9 ( 7.9 is the last version from 7.X ) and its from last 1.5 year

Comment: @KingDavid, to have support you need special contracts! Or use RHEL 8, 9.

Comment: yes we have contract with RHEL , and also support , we can open cases etc ,

Comment: If you do not have ELS you will finish with support at June 30, 2024. Check this page: https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/errata#Life_Cycle_Dates

Comment: In addition to my answer, I thought it was funny, but I coincidentally got a notification from Nvidia about this today https://docs.nvidia.com/dgx/dgx-rhel-sw-release-notes/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dell engineer here - as Greg Andrew mentioned your first stop is RHEL’s site to check what servers they support. Dell internally does testing with multiple versions of RHEL and I still run into RHEL 7 on customer sites routinely. I actually did a new install of a VxRail for a customer running RHEL 7 in a bunch of VMs yesterday.

Realistically RHEL will run on most things. The key is driver / processor architecture support - ex if you’re going to run an R7525 you’d want to make sure that the RHEL kernel is going to play nicely with the AMD Epyc procs. If you guys have any special PCIe devices for an HPC environment, make sure those are supported.

Regarding your question

> How do you know something is 15G?

The second digit in the model number. For PowerEdge Rack servers all the Intel servers are three digits R650, R750, etc and all the AMD servers are 4 digits - R6515, R7515, R7525 etc.

The second digit indicates the generation. So 14G you would see R640, R740, etc whereas 15G is R650, R750…

In my experience, despite its age, RHEL 7 still will at least install on most servers. Laptops not so much - I’ve seen a lot of NVMe problems there because Red Hat isn’t adding support for newer things. As other people have mentioned though, if at all possible, I would depart from RHEL 7 sooner rather than later. It’s not receiving new support patches so you will be on your own for most things and I’m sure you will see more and more hardware compatibility problems.